# Menu with "fn F" as hotkey

Tags: swift, macos

How do I setup a menu item with "fn F" as the hotkey? This is typically used as a hotkey to toggle Enter and Exit Fullscreen. I tried

```swift
fullscreen.keyEquivalentModifierMask = [.function]
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, this is not possible with `keyEquivalentModifierMask`. You would need to detect the key press yourself, and then run the button's action.

Comment: Or if you read the HIG you see you shouldn’t do it at all.

Comment: The standard Fullscreen hotkey is Control-Command-F, see [Standard keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/keyboards#Standard-keyboard-shortcuts). My Logitech keyboard doesn't support hotkeys with fn.

Comment: @Willeke, thanks for the link. Strange that all Apple's products like Safari, Pages and others are using "Fn F" which is what I was trying to do. I will go with Control-Command-F.

Comment: The default full screen menu item in the Xcode app template has key equivalent Control-Command-F. `NSApplication` adds a menu item with key equivalent Fn-F and hides the Control-Command-F item in `finishLaunching`.